# Ordering categories alphabetically in Prestashop top menu

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have set up a Prestashop 1.7 website for a client and I'm importing his new products with a script every day. These products are put in categories that I create if they don't yet exist. My problem is that the newly created categories are put at the end of the drop down top menu, and it would be much better to have them displayed alphabetically. I know I can do that in the back office by drag and dropping them in place, but I want my script to do it automatically.

I've already overriden the `Category.php`class to make other changes so I can edit this file. I tried to change every `ORDER BY` clauses I found from `depth` or `position` to `name`. It had some effects as categories were indeed sorted by name but a lot of them simply disappeared from the menu (i.e. out of say 10 categories sorted by position, only 4 remained sorted by name).

Do you know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this 2 ways.
My approach is to do this when the menu is created, this way it's sorted in every language. To do so, just use this override for ps_mainmenu module:

```
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Module\WidgetInterface;

class Ps_MainMenuOverride extends Ps_MainMenu implements WidgetInterface
{
    protected function generateCategoriesMenu($categories, $is_children = 0)
    {
        $categories = $this->sortCategories($categories);
        return parent::generateCategoriesMenu($categories, $is_children);
    }

    public function sortCategories($categories)
    {

        uasort($categories, 'cmpcat');

        foreach($categories as $k => $category)
        {
            if (isset($category['children']) && !empty($category['children'])) {
                $children = $this->sortCategories($category['children']);
                $categories[$k]['children'] = $children;
            }
        }
        return $categories;
    }
}

function cmpcat($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}
```

The other option is to sort when creating the menu. But I would have to see the current import code, and even then could be more difficult.

This is for the children categories. For the main categories it would be necessary to override another function.

Comment: Hello, I tried it. I copied the code and pasted at the end of the ps_mainmenu.php file. But I guess I have to change code somewhere else, because it is not working for me.
What else I have to change?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Chebe have you created the override file and cleared the cache? In 1.7 you need to delete the folder app/cache/dev and/or app/cache/prod. Are you using a custom theme that doesn't use the default functions?

Comment: @sadlyblue Thank you! I was doing it in the wrong file. I have no idea about the override folder. This article point me in the right direction: http://nemops.com/override-prestashop-modules-core/#.W18eRtgzZTZ

Now its working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the query, if, for example, the child category name starts with a and parent with b, prestashop doesn't show it, you must add a primary "order by", in this case: level_depth.

I hope my override code will be useful:

```
    use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Module\WidgetInterface;

    class Ps_MainMenuOverride extends Ps_MainMenu  implements WidgetInterface
    {
        protected function makeMenu()
        {
            $root_node = $this->makeNode([
                'label' => null,
                'type'  => 'root',
                'children' => []
            ]);

            $menu_items = $this->getMenuItems();
            $id_lang = (int)$this->context->language->id;
            $id_shop = (int)Shop::getContextShopID();

            foreach ($menu_items as $item) {
                if (!$item) {
                    continue;
                }
                preg_match($this->pattern, $item, $value);
                $id = (int)substr($item, strlen($value[1]), strlen($item));

                switch (substr($item, 0, strlen($value[1]))) {
                    case 'CAT':
                        $categories = $this->generateCategoriesMenu(
                            Category::getNestedCategories($id, $id_lang, false, $this->user_groups,true,'',' ORDER BY c.`level_depth`,cl.`name` ASC ')
                        );
                        $root_node['children'] = array_merge($root_node['children'], $categories);
                        break;

                    case 'PRD':
                        $product = new Product((int)$id, true, (int)$id_lang);
                        if ($product->id) {
                            $root_node['children'][] = $this->makeNode([
                                'type' => 'product',
                                'page_identifier' => 'product-' . $product->id,
                                'label' => $product->name,
                                'url' => $product->getLink(),
                            ]);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'CMS':
                        $cms = CMS::getLinks((int)$id_lang, array($id));
                        if (count($cms)) {
                            $root_node['children'][] = $this->makeNode([
                                'type' => 'cms-page',
                                'page_identifier' => 'cms-page-' . $id,
                                'label' => $cms[0]['meta_title'],
                                'url' => $cms[0]['link']
                            ]);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'CMS_CAT':
                        $root_node['children'][] = $this->generateCMSCategoriesMenu((int)$id, (int)$id_lang);
                        break;

                    // Case to handle the option to show all Manufacturers
                    case 'ALLMAN':
                        $children = array_map(function ($manufacturer) use ($id_lang) {
                            return $this->makeNode([
                                'type' => 'manufacturer',
                                'page_identifier' => 'manufacturer-' . $manufacturer['id_manufacturer'],
                                'label' => $manufacturer['name'],
                                'url' => $this->context->link->getManufacturerLink(
                                    new Manufacturer($manufacturer['id_manufacturer'], $id_lang),
                                    null,
                                    $id_lang
                                )
                            ]);
                        }, Manufacturer::getManufacturers());

                        $root_node['children'][] = $this->makeNode([
                            'type' => 'manufacturers',
                            'page_identifier' => 'manufacturers',
                            'label' => $this->trans('All brands', array(), 'Modules.Mainmenu.Admin'),
                            'url' => $this->context->link->getPageLink('manufacturer'),
                            'children' => $children
                        ]);
                        break;

                    case 'MAN':
                        $manufacturer = new Manufacturer($id, $id_lang);
                        if ($manufacturer->id) {
                            $root_node['children'][] = $this->makeNode([
                                'type' => 'manufacturer',
                                'page_identifier' => 'manufacturer-' . $manufacturer->id,
                                'label' => $manufacturer->name,
                                'url' => $this->context->link->getManufacturerLink(
                                    $manufacturer,
                                    null,
                                    $id_lang
                                )
                            ]);
                        }
                        break;

                    // Case to handle the option to show all Suppliers
                    case 'ALLSUP':
                        $children = array_map(function ($supplier) use ($id_lang) {
                            return $this->makeNode([
                                'type' => 'supplier',
                                'page_identifier' => 'supplier-' . $supplier['id_supplier'],
                                'label' => $supplier['name'],
                                'url' => $this->context->link->getSupplierLink(
                                    new Supplier($supplier['id_supplier'], $id_lang),
                                    null,
                                    $id_lang
                                )
                            ]);
                        }, Supplier::getSuppliers());

                        $root_node['children'][] = $this->makeNode([
                            'type' => 'suppliers',
                            'page_identifier' => 'suppliers',
                            'label' => $this->trans('All suppliers', array(), 'Modules.Mainmenu.Admin'),
                            'url' => $this->context->link->getPageLink('supplier'),
                            'children' => $children
                        ]);
                        break;

                    case 'SUP':
                        $supplier = new Supplier($id, $id_lang);
                        if ($supplier->id) {
                            $root_node['children'][] = $this->makeNode([
                                'type' => 'supplier',
                                'page_identifier' => 'supplier-' . $supplier->id,
                                'label' => $supplier->name,
                                'url' => $this->context->link->getSupplierLink(
                                    $supplier,
                                    null,
                                    $id_lang
                                )
                            ]);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'SHOP':
                        $shop = new Shop((int)$id);
                        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($shop)) {
                            $root_node['children'][] = $this->makeNode([
                                'type' => 'shop',
                                'page_identifier' => 'shop-' . $id,
                                'label' => $shop->name,
                                'url' => $shop->getBaseURL(),
                            ]);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'LNK':
                        $link = Ps_MenuTopLinks::get($id, $id_lang, $id_shop);
                        if (!empty($link)) {
                            if (!isset($link[0]['label']) || ($link[0]['label'] == '')) {
                                $default_language = Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
                                $link = Ps_MenuTopLinks::get($link[0]['id_linksmenutop'], $default_language, (int)Shop::getContextShopID());
                            }
                            $root_node['children'][] = $this->makeNode([
                                'type' => 'link',
                                'page_identifier' => 'lnk-' . Tools::str2url($link[0]['label']),
                                'label' => $link[0]['label'],
                                'url' => $link[0]['link'],
                                'open_in_new_window' => $link[0]['new_window']
                            ]);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return $this->mapTree(function ($node, $depth) {
                $node['depth'] = $depth;
                return $node;
            }, $root_node);
        }

    }
```